# Setting SharePoint locale / language based on Domain?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, language, localization, alternate-language

We are trying to set the Culture on our sites and initially it seems to have worked but we've noticed that when we navigate to sites and we get the `"Working on it"` this isn't getting translated to the set language. Additionally, with grouped views, the column values for the grouped columns are not getting translated as well.

We noticed that to get the translations to work as expected for these items, I had to change the locale of the Browsers to French. **What is the browser providing to SharePoint that we can handle through code instead?**

Right now through code we're determining locale based on english vs french domain. This is how we're setting language:

```
HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
HttpContext ctx = app.Context; 
currentLang = Helper.GetUrlLanguage(ctx.request, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current); // Returns 1033 or 1036

System.Globalization.CultureInfo newCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureId);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;

Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.SetThreadCulture(newCulture, newCulture);
```

Currently on the french site I see this:

[image]